# ruby rspec in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, rspec

I have problems with error message ./spec/models/lib/parsers/s_reality_cz/matcher_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in ' in every rspec test. What I'm doing wrong? Using rspec-rails 3.5. Thanks

Code:
    require 'rails_helper'

```
RSpec.describe Parsers::SRealityCz::Matcher, :type=> :model do
  before do
    @doc = File.open("spec/fixtures/srealitycz_profile.html") { |f| Nokogiri::HTML(f) }
  end

  let(:parser) { described_class }

  it "returns total price" do
    expect(parser.title(@doc)).to eq "Prodej bytu 1+kk 40 m²"
  end
end
```

Rspec output:

```
Randomized with seed 37464


expected: "Prodej bytu 1+kk 40 m²"
     got: "Prodej bytu 1+kk 40 m²"

(compared using ==)

./spec/models/lib/parsers/s_reality_cz/matcher_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'

1 example, 1 failure, 0 passed

Finished in 0.139173354 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your strings look the same, but they probably have different encodings.
Convert them both to the same encoding (e.g. `UTF-8`), and compare them.

Comment: How easy :) Thanks you